# What is the default range for IntegerFields on Django?

Tags: django

Such a simple question, but can't seem to find anything [in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/fields/#integerfield) about it.

For example, can integers be negative?

Comment: The exact range depends on the database backend, not on Django.

Comment: @wim - oh right. can you make that an answer or should i delete the question?

Comment: As a FormField it is not dependent on the database backend. As a ModelField it is, but the validation is on the FormField.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is none. Any integer is valid. Negative is definitely fine. But the IntegerField is not limited by default. [#16747 closed Bug (wontfix) IntegerField could validate too large numbers to work with PostgreSQL and MySQL be default](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16747)  was a request to fix this, but it was denied.

Keep in mind that an IntegerField is not necessarily connected to a particular database field. It usually is, in which case the recommendation is to add  max_value and min_value to match your database field requirements.

Comment: What do you think of the other answer that says -2147483648 to 2147483647

Comment: That answer is correct for *model* fields. The question was about *form* fields.

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about `models.IntegerField` then there is indeed a range for that and it is mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.IntegerField).

> An integer. Values from -2147483648 to 2147483647 are safe in all
>   databases supported by Django.
>
> It uses MinValueValidator and MaxValueValidator to validate the input
>   based on the values that the default database supports.

If you're talking about `forms.IntegerField`, then the only way to validate it is to pass a parameter of [max_value and min_value](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/fields/#integerfield) for that.

> Validates that the given value is an integer. Uses MaxValueValidator
>   and MinValueValidator if max_value and min_value are provided.